# Incrementing values in table using PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my query I'm using a for loop, which displays 1000 three times. I have to increment 1000 for each iteration of the loop, i.e. 1001, 1002,.. same number three times i.e. I want to add into my table 1000,1000,1000,1001,1001,1001 and 1002,1002,1002,

```
declare
   CPName varchar(20) :=1000;
   a number; 
begin
   for a in 1 .. 3 loop
       insert into clients values (CPName,null,null);
   end loop;    
end;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

`CPName` is a VARCHAR; I assume you want this to be a number, in which case you just add it on.

There's no need to define the variable `a` either, it's implicitly declared by the LOOP. I would call this `i` as it's a more common name for an index variable.

```
declare
   CPName integer := 1000;
begin
   for i in 1 .. 3 loop
       insert into clients values (CPName + i, null, null);
   end loop;    
end;
```

You can do this all in a single SQL statement though; there's no need to use PL/SQL.

```
insert into clients
 select 1000 + i, null, null
   from dual
  cross join ( select level as i
                 from dual
              connect by level <= 3 )
```

---

Based on your comments you actually want something like this:

```
insert into clients
with multiply as (
 select level - 1 as i
   from dual
connect by level <= 3
        )
 select 1000 + m.i, null, null
   from dual
  cross join multiply m
  cross join multiply
```

This will only work if you want the same number of records as you want to increase so maybe you'd prefer to do it this way, which will give you a lot more flexibility:

```
insert into clients
with increments as (
 select level - 1 as i
   from dual
connect by level <= 5
        )
, iterations as (
 select level as j
   from dual
connect by level <= 3
        )
 select 1000 + m.i, null, null
   from dual
  cross join increments m
  cross join iterations
```

Using your LOOP methodology this would involve a second, interior loop:

```
declare
   CPName integer := 1000;
begin
   for i in 1 .. 3 loop
      for j in 1 .. 3 loop
         insert into clients values (CPName + i, null, null);
      end loop;
   end loop;    
end;
```

Comment: You can't "increment" a VARCHAR variable; the concept doesn't exist. However, if you use the ASCII() function then yes, you can use the same method.